# Show expected value is continuous

Tags: integration, probability-theory, continuity, expected-value

I am trying to show the expectation operator is continuous on the following random variable  $X_2$ as a function of $c$

$$X_2=\begin{cases}
     -X_1^2 & \text{if }  |X_1|\leq c \\
      X_1^2 & \text{if } |X_1|>c\\
\end{cases}$$

where $X_1\sim N(0,1)$.

My attempt:

Let $\mathbb{M}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid |X_1(\omega)|\leq c \}$ then

$$E[X_2]=\int_{\Omega}X_2(\omega)dP(\omega)=\int_{\mathbb{M}}X_2(\omega)dP(\omega)+\int_{M^{c}}X_2(\omega)dP(\omega)$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{M}}-X_1^2(\omega)dP(\omega)+\int_{M^{c}}X_1^2(\omega)dP(\omega)\leq\int_{\Omega}c^2dP(\omega)+\int_{\Omega}X_1^2(\omega)dP(\omega)=c^2+1$$

then I  can bound

$$E[X_2(c)]-E[X_2(c_o)]\leq c^2-c_o^2=(c-c_o)(c+c_o)$$

I am having trouble finding a proper $\delta$ to  get me within $\epsilon$

Comment: There is something wrong with the first statement of your question. I doubt  $X_2$ is a standard Gaussian as you claim it is.

Comment: sorry you are right. The original statement defined another group of random variables as Y=X_1 or -X_1 with the same set as above. Y is a normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll denote $Y_c = \begin{cases} -X_1^2 & |X_1| \le c \\ X_1^2 & |X_1| > c \end{cases}$. You want to check if $\mathbb E[Y_{c+h} - Y_c] \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

Note that for $h>0$ we have
$$ E[Y_{c+h}-Y_c] = \mathbb E[-2X_1^2 1_{|X_1| \in (c,c+h)} ] \to 0$$ by dominated convergence theorem ($2|X_1|^2$ is an integrable function)

Similarly for $h<0$ we have:

$$ E[Y_{c+h} - Y_c] = \mathbb E[ 2X_1^2 1_{\{|X_1| \in (c-h,c)\}}] \to 0 $$

Again by dominated convergence (with the same reasons). Since we showed the limits as $h\to 0^+$ and $h \to 0^-$, it follows that $$ \lim_{h \to 0}\mathbb E[Y_{c+h}-Y_c] = 0$$

Comment: Just to clarify. Since $Y_{c+h}$ converges  to $Y_c$ and it is dominated by an integrable measurable function then by DCT  we are guaranteed the integral of the difference goes to zero.

Comment: We're using dominated convergence for functions $f(h) = 2|X_1|^2 1_{|X_1| \in (c,c+h)}$ which converges pointwise to $0$, and is dominated by $2|X_1|^2 $

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, if $X_1\sim N(0,1)$ and

$$X_c=-X^2_1\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1|\leq c\}} + X^2_1\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1|>c\}}=-2X^2_1\mathbb{1}_{\{|X_1|\leq c\}}+X^2_1
$$

you want to know whether $\phi(c)=\mathbb{E}[X_c]$ is continuous. If that is the case, notice that for $0\leq c<c'$

$$
\begin{align*}
|\phi(c')-\phi(c)|&=2\Big(\int^{c'}_c x^2\,\Phi(dx)+\int^{-c}_{-c'}x^2\,\Phi(dx)\Big)=4 \int^{c'}_c x^2\,\Phi(dx)\\
&\leq 4(c')^2\,\mathbb{P}(c<X_1\leq c')=4(c')^2\,\big(\Phi(c')-\Phi(c)\big)
\end{align*}
$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Is The last part meant to show as $c$ $\rightarrow$ $c^{'}$ the upper bound goes to zero therefore the difference goes zero

Comment: If $c'\rightarrow c$ then the right hand side of last inequality goes to $0$ since $\Phi(c')-\Phi(c)\rightarrow0$. Similarly, if $c\rightarrow c'$, then the right hand side goes to $0$ for similar reasons.